# XSLT Syntax Error when copying and replacing element values in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to create a XSLT to copy and replace a few elements in a XML document.  I came up with this but kept getting "Syntax error in XPath expression" error.  The tool I'm using is WMHelp XMLPad and it doesn't give me any more details on what the syntax error is.  Please help.  Thanks.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:tx="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="currenYearContrAmt" select="'20.00'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="contrFAId" select="'FINANCIAL_ACTIVITY_ACH_1_1'" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template  
match="//tx:FinancialActivity[@id=$contrFAId]/tx:OLifEExtension/tx:CurrentYearContributionAmt/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="$currenYearContrAmt"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The error cannot be reproduced using (only) your code.

Comment: Confirmed, there is nothing wrong with the syntax of your stylesheet. Please also show a sample input XML document that you would like to transform (and, of course, that throws this error).

Comment: Are you definitely using an XSLT 2.0 processor? The version number of the XSLT file shows "2.0", but you will still need a processor that handles XSLT 2.0. If you were using an XSLT 1.0 processor, it can still run the stylesheet, but you may get an error because variables are not allowed in template matches in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I tried using a different xsl transformer and it worked!!  Thanks for confirming the correctness of the xsl.